# how to fix error C2460 in c++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct link
{
    link data;
    link* next;
};
class linklist
{
private:
    link* first;
public:
    linklist()
    {first=NULL;}
    void additem(int d);
    void display();
};
void linklist::additem(int d)
{
    link* newlink=new link;
    newlink->data=d;
    newlink->next=first;
    first=newlink;
}
void linklist::display()
{
    int n=0;
    link* current=new link;
    current=first;
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"The link data number"<<++n<<"is"<<current->data<<endl;
        current=current->next;
    }
    if(current==NULL)
        cout<<"This is empty linkedlist"<<endl;
};
int main()
{
    linklist li;
    li.additem(25);
    li.additem(36);
    li.additem(49);
    li.additem(64);
    li.display();
    return 0;
}
```

i got this error while i compile this code (error C2460: 'data' : uses 'link', which is being defined) and i can't fix it , please any help
i got this error while i compile this code (error C2460: 'data' : uses 'link', which is being defined) and i can't fix it , please any help

Comment: Perhaps use `struct link` inside of the struct when defining members that are self-referential to the struct?

Comment: Every `link` has a `link` inside it, plus some other stuff. How do you expect that to work? That would mean a `link` would have to be infinitely big!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution for your exact problem since you are using the `data` field to store integers only.

```
struct link
{
    int data;
    link* next;
};
```

As for the error, the error is pretty clear: the compiler doesn't know how much space it needs to reserve for your "link data" member, since the class "link" is still being defined. The problem doesn't happen with pointers because no matter what type of pointer is, they all use the same amount of space, which is normally 32bits or 64bits depending on your settings.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct link
{
    link data;
```

This is illegal. An object cannot contain itself, as a class member.